# change the image of the button not changing when clicked

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

i have a button that i want the image to change after data updated. but not sure how this should be don 
this is what i have so far

```
- (IBAction)LikeBtn:(id)sender {

This code not needed for this site

    // Save new Post object in Parse
    [newPost saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"liked");
            [self likedSuccess];

             [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"liked.png"]];

        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Error");
            [self likedFail];
        }

    }];

}
```

anyone any ideas?

im getting the erro when button clicked

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton setBackgroundImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x110158b60'`
```

Comment: what is the problem by far?? I think you need to cast the sender to a UIbutton: UIButton * button = (UIButton*)sender;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you seeing `liked` getting logged out? Are you sure you're not receiving errors? Try `NSLog(@"Error: %@", error)` in the else branch see what gets logged out into the console.

Also since sender is an `id`, you probably want to do some introspection like make sure

```
[sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]
```

before setting back ground image.

Also the correct method call to set background image is `setBackgroundImage:forState:`, check the reference here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setBackgroundImage:forState:

There is no `setBackgroundImage`.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton setBackgroundImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x110158b60'

Comment: @MikeJAspinall the state you want is probably UIControlStateNormal? But read the docs just to make sure you know what you need.